# If Else statement not working as expected when passing arguments with spaces

Tags: python, if-statement, argv

I have a simple if-else that takes a command-line argument and returns a value from a dictionary.  When I enter 'Darth Vader', it returns 'Luke, I am your None' instead of 'No, I am your father'.

It works as expected with all other keys in the dictionary.  Here is the code:

```
import sys

relations = {'Darth Vader': 'father', 'Leia': 'sister', 'Han': 'brother in law',
'R2D2': 'droid', 'Rey': 'Padawan', 'Tatooine': 'homeworld'}

key = sys.argv[1]

if key == 'Darth Vader':
  print("No, I am  your father")
else:
  print('Luke, I am your', relations.get(key))
```

Comment: This is probably because `Darth Vader` is two words.  Try calling it with quotes around the argument

Answer (score 1):

```
key = sys.argv[1]
```

This gives you the second argument from the `cmd` (command line), but this leads to an error, since with the space between "Darth" and "Vader" makes "Darth" to be the only second argument.

Comment: It doesn't lead to an error, it just does something different than expected.

Answer (score 0):

As said Patrick Haugh, you should rename `Darth Vader` `Darth_Vader`, or use quotes (`"Darth Vader"`) in your arguments instead of `Darth Vader`.